# Cannot apply [*] operation to types [org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Doubles] and [java.lang.Double]

Tags: elasticsearch

**Here is the mappeing of the attribute for the index-**
"hoi" : {
"type" : "float"
}

**This is the query that I want to execute. I want to change my attribute hoi with dynamic value and sort the doc on top of that, don't want to use runtime mapping as I have lower version of ES-**

```
GET test/_search
{
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['hoi'] * params.factor",
                "params" : {
                    "factor" : 1.1
                }
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

**Error-**

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "runtime error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "doc['hoi'] * params.factor",
          "                                        ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "doc['hoi'] * params.factor",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 40,
          "start" : 0,
          "end" : 47
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "test",
        "node" : "5sfrbDiLQDOg82_sneaU1g",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "doc['hoi'] * params.factor",
            "                                        ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "doc['hoi'] * params.factor",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "position" : {
            "offset" : 40,
            "start" : 0,
            "end" : 47
          },
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "class_cast_exception",
            "reason" : "Cannot apply [*] operation to types [org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Doubles] and [java.lang.Double]."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`doc['hoi']` itself is of type `org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Doubles` and `params.factor` is of type `java.lang.Double`.

So the error you get means that some document has multiple values in your `hoi` field. So you need to reference it with `doc['hoi'].value * params.factor` instead, which will take the first `hoi` value from the array to compute the sort.

You can also check how many values there are with `doc['hoi'].size()`.

**UPDATE**

If some docs don't have any values for `hoi` then you can adapt the script like this:

```
doc['hoi'].size() > 0 ? doc['hoi'].value * params.factor : 0
```

Comment: It's not having multiple values but this helped as some docs were not having HOI, filtering those docs out worked. Thanks.
But any idea how can I accommodate docs which are not having HOI values also in this.